403 Forbidden when using ytdl-core
Recently, I attempted to download a YouTube video using a custom program that uses ytdl-core on NPM. However, after attempting several URLs, I received 403 Forbidden through all of them.
Sample code is below:
import { ytdl } from "ytdl-core";
import * as fs from "node:fs";

// ...

const info = ytdl.getInfo("some-video-id");

const stream = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, { filter: 'videoandaudio' });
fs.createWriteStream(`${makeSafe(info.videoDetails.title)}.mp4`);


YouTube recently released an update that breaks most video downloaders. The change implements new requirements that when failed, result in a 403 Forbidden response. Unfortunately, as ytdl-core is no longer actively maintained, it is recommended that you move to @distube/ytdl-core. The maintainers on that package have released a fix in commit 3df824e that patches the issue present here. To move, follow these steps:

Uninstall ytdl-core to prevent conflicting packages with the same name

npm uninstall ytdl-core


Install @distube/ytdl-core at the latest version

npm install @distube/ytdl-core@latest


Replace references of the old package with @distube/ytdl-core

Anywhere that you use the old ytdl-core package, put the new @distube/ytdl-core package. This can be as simple as rewriting your imports.

Examples:
import { ytdl } from "@distube/ytdl-core"; // ESM

const ytdl = require("@distube/ytdl-core"); // CommonJS


It's still not working...

Did you update your package to the latest and remove all uses of the outdated package?

I did... The current script player base.js is different from the previous one that was generated on the day i made the previous comment

Try to check if it's already working

It's worked for me and many others. Post a question with your implementation. This sounds like a specific issue with your code

Can you share the working code please, let me know if it's from my code because i tested it recently but the urls cannot be played

You should post a question with your implementation. We can't help you if we don't know what's going wrong or see anything

Docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@distube/ytdl-core say to use const ytdl = require("@distube/ytdl-core"); instead of import. import wasn't working (even though my other imports are).

I was using ESM in my answer. You're likely using CommonJS. I'll add a little bit in my answer to account for that @Ryan
